# select query on non existen data if/else

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am doing a select to display my database and I want to do a `if/else`.

The problem here is that if there is something to retrive it works but when there are no columns  (the query does not exists) the  `if ($row3f=="")` does not works. It is not empty, it simply doesn't exists.

How can I perform an if does not exists?

```
} else{ ?>

$strSQLsavedf = "SELECT url_recibo from bruno_wallet_saved where contador='{$contador_file}'  "; 
$rssavedf = mysql_query($strSQLsavedf);
while($row3f = mysql_fetch_array($rssavedf)) { 
$hideupload="#upload_".$fid;

if ($row3f=="") { 

} else{ ?>
   <a style="margin-left:20px;" href="<?php echo $row3f[0];?>">Recibo: 
 <img src="http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/images/recibo1.png"  height="16" width="16"> </a> </P> 

 <?php

};

   } ;
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array, not a string.

Comment: You mean `$row3f['url_recibo']`

Comment: dont work ! im guessing thats becouse the select dosent return anything in some cases whe variable $contador_file dosent exists on the db... can i do a if error or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($row3f == "")
```

should be

```
if ($row3f['url_recibo'] == "")
```

because `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array, not a string.

But you could simply make the query not return these rows in the first place. Change the SQL to

```
$strSQLsavedf = "SELECT url_recibo 
                 from bruno_wallet_saved 
                 where contador='{$contador_file}' AND url_recibo != '' ";
```

If you want to print a message if nothing is selected, check the number of rows returned:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($rssavedf) == 0) {
    echo "No matches";
} else {
    while ($row3f = mysql_fetch_array($rssavedf)) {
        ?>
        <a style="margin-left:20px;" href="<?php echo $row3f[0];?>">Recibo: 
        <img src="http://www.toppromomkt.com/wp-content/themes/toppromo/images/recibo1.png"  height="16" width="16"> </a> </P> 
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: dont work ! im guessing thats becouse the select dosent return anything in some cases whe variable $contador_file dosent exists on the db... can i do a if error or something ?

Comment: If the query doesn't return anything, the loop will finish immediately without printing anything. What are you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: If you want to print a message if there are no matches, use `if (mysql_num_rows($rssavedf) == 0)`

Comment: nevermind it worked... i was calling the line to earlier ... tks barmar